# In Magento 2.2.0 after disable the template path hint the some pages still show the path hint

Tags: magento2, cache, magento2.2, full-page-cache

In Magento-2.2.0 after disable the template path hint some pages still show the path hint,

I clear all the caches and but still same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your **var/generation** and **generated** directory from your magento root directory

- run php bin/magento setup:di:compile command
- run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy command
- run php bin/magento cache:clean command
- run php bin/magento cache:flush command

Then check path hint will not shown.

**Note : Make sure you have disabled the path hint from backend**